# DIY CNC Machine Power Requirements

Tags: arduino-mega, power, motor, stepper

I want to make a CNC machine that uses 5 NEMA 17 rated for 2A and a RAMPS 1.4 to control it all. I have a power supply that can deliver 1.5A at 12V. Is it enough? I am worried that when all 5 motors are under load, the amperage will get distributed and there will be very low amperage per motor.

Comment: 5x2 is 10. You need at least that and more.

Comment: So I need at least 10 amps!

Comment: Is there any cheap place I can get that type of power supply? Also how much can an ATX power supply give out?

Comment: Yes, and more than that - here's an example https://cpc.farnell.com/unbranded/500w-builder-black/500w-black-12cm-psu-pfc/dp/CS32144?mckv=saBqmjUHB_dm|pcrid|395592567287|kword||match||plid||slid||product|CS32144|pgrid|83089512472|ptaid|pla-781001870297|&CMP=KNC-GUK-CPC-SHOPPING&gclid=Cj0KCQiA7qP9BRCLARIsABDaZzj6FBitKJ-pzTDlGUG-ci5LeuKl5bZcNUPqsTcVxTOlGW2Q3VvgLxoaArTlEALw_wcB

Comment: You can limit the current on some stepper driver modules by adjusting a potentiometer. But that results in less torque in the stepper motor. Not ideal, but it might be useful, so you can move forward while waiting for a proper power supply.

Comment: PS on ATX power supplies to need to connect the green wire (PS_ON) to GND (black wire), to enable it.

Comment: Some also need a load on the 3.3v or 5v to operate.

Comment: Is there near the 5-10 USD range?

Comment: Here's one that's $14.50. I'm personally not a fan of using ATX power supplies as general power supplies. Mornsun isn't a very known brand 
but we using them for all our power supplies at my company and they are just as good for the faction of the cost. https://store.nacsemi.com/products/detail?part=LM150-20B12&stock=MS000000009106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring out your current needs is simply a matter of adding everything up. If you have 5 2 amp motors, you'll need 5 x 2, or 10 amps just to drive the motors.

You should probably have at least 20% extra capacity, so I'd suggest having a 12V power supply that can put out at least 12A.

15A would be better.

The stiffer your power supply the less it will "bobble" as the load varies.

Comment: That's not really how stepper motors behave in practice, since their rated currents occur at much lower voltages than Vcc under use.
5A should be fine for five such steppers.